# vlookup split value VBA

Tags: vba, excel, split, vlookup

I have created macro that works like a vlookup but has split values. I would like to find value from second sheet of split values (separated by semicolon ) and copy and paste the description to new sheet.

The first loop goes through the list in sheet 2 and sets the value in a variable, the second loop through split values checks when there is exact match  and the description is copied and pasted to the second sheet.

However - it doesn't work and I don't know what the problem is.

I have notification `"type mismatch"`.

I tried vlookup with part text string but it doesn't work either.

[image]

```
Sub Metadane()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long
Dim myAr

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim bCell As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim variable As String

'~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    '~~> Find the last row in Col A
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)

Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 With ws2
    '~~> Find the last row in Col A
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Set your range
    Set rng2 = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)
    '~~> Loop trhough your range
    For Each bCell In rng2
         If Len(Trim(bCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
         variable = bCell.Value

        For Each aCell In rng
            '~~> Skip the row if value in cell A is blank
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Check if the cell has ";"
                '~~> If it has ";" then loop through values
                If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ";") Then
                    myAr = Split(aCell.Value, ";")

                    For i = LBound(myAr) To UBound(myAr)
                        If myAr = variable Then
                        Worksheets("sheet2").bCell(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Next i

                Else
                    Worksheets("sheet2").bCell(, 2).PasteSpecial     xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        Next

        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

I changed my code but it is still not work properly, I have a result:

[image]

Comment: `If myAr = variable Then` you should add `End If` for this statement.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful, but still I have a problem. Now "Run time error'13'. Type mismatch"

Comment: You are comparing a string with an array. `myAr = variable`. I believe that is your error? You need to change it to `myAr(i) = variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Cl As Range, Key As Variant
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each Cl In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
            If Cl.Value <> "" Then
                Dic.Add Cl.Row & "|" & Replace(LCase(Cl.Value), ";", "||") & "|", Cl.Offset(, 1).Text
            End If
        Next Cl
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each Cl In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
            For Each Key In Dic
                If Key Like "*|" & LCase(Cl.Value) & "|*" And Cl.Value <> "" Then
                    Cl.Offset(, 1).Value = Dic(Key)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Key
        Next Cl
    End With
End Sub
```

Output Result

[image]

Comment: @user3114375 thnks, also `lcase` has been added to remove case sensitivity, due to `"A"` not equal `"a"`

Comment: with my real data I had error "Invalid pattern string". it can be problem connected with special characters: . (), "". I change my code:  'If Key Like "[[]*" & LCase(Cl.Value) & "*[]]" And Cl.Value <> "" Then' Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @user3114375 no, the problem you faced with "invalid pattern string" described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38645c8s(v=vs.90).aspx, please see my updated post, `"["` replaced by `"|"`, now code must works well

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub YourVLookup()

    Dim rng As Variant, rng2 As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim aCell As Variant, bCell As Variant
    Dim myAr() As String, variable As String

    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B"&lastRow)
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B"&lastRow)

    For i = LBound(rng2, 1) To UBound(rng2, 1)
        If Len(Trim(rng2(i, 1))) <> 0 Then
            variable = rng2(i, 1)
            For j = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
                If Len(Trim(rng(j, 1))) <> 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, rng(j, 1), ";") > 0 Then
                        myAr = Split(rng(j, 1))
                        For k = LBound(myAr) To UBound(myAr)
                            If myAr(k) = variable Then
                                rng2(i, 2) = myAr(k)
                            End If
                        Next k
                    ElseIf rng(j, 1) = rng2(i, 1) Then
                        rng2(i, 2) = rng(j, 2)
                    End If
                End if
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B"&lastRow) = rng
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B"&lastRow) = rng2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pasting something that you don't have copied already, you forgot to close a `With`, and you can't use `bCell(,2)`, so

Try this :

```
Sub Metadane()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim Lrow As Long, i As Long
Dim myAr() As String

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim bCell As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim variable As String

'~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    '~~> Find the last row in Col A
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)
End With


Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
With ws2
    '~~> Find the last row in Col A
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Set your range
    Set rng2 = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)
    '~~> Loop trhough your range
    For Each bCell In rng2
        If Len(Trim(bCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
            variable = bCell.Value
            For Each aCell In rng
                '~~> Skip the row if value in cell A is blank
                If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                    '~~> Check if the cell has ";"
                    '~~> If it has ";" then loop through values
                    If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ";") Then
                        myAr = Split(aCell.Value, ";")
                        For i = LBound(myAr) To UBound(myAr)
                            If myAr(i) <> variable Then
                            Else
                                'You were pasting nothing with that
                                '.bCell(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                                .Cells(bCell.Row, 2) = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

                            End If
                        Next i
                    Else
                        'Same here
                        '.bCell(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        .Cells(bCell.Row, 2) = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

                    End If
                End If
            Next aCell

        End If
    Next bCell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have the same error: Type mismatch. Maybe there is a problem with variables.

Comment: On which line? Always gave error with line and description

Comment: `If myAr(i) <> variable Then`

Comment: Ok it's just that the array supposed to get the `split` result wasn't well declared. see the edit : `Dim myAr() as String`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now but not properly. It return only last description for value a.

Comment: Can you detail a bot more or add a screenshot?

Comment: I add sreenshot above in question

Comment: I believe `Rows.Count` always returns `1` in `.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Value`.

Comment: Mkay... So your code is not really a Vlookup... What do you want then? To add manually the values in Sheet2 and then run macro, **or** that the macro write value in A column expending the Sheet1 data to its fullest?

Comment: Or even just a function to work as Vlookup, I mean to be used directly into the workbook. Tell me so I can edit the code! ;)

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst : No the `Rows.Count` will return you the maximal number of rows in your documents (difference between Xl2003 and further)
The problem come from the algorithm itself, as we used 2 loops, but one is probably working on an empty range so it's messing everything!

Comment: It will return the maximum numbers of Rows in the column given. When the first row is empty it will return 1, when the first row is not empty it will return 1. In any way your code is overwriting the last row in the sheet.

Comment: The problem is that searched data (sheet2) are splitted value and vlookup function not working for this values, I have a hundreds data to match with description.

Comment: @user3114375 : Mkay so I guess that means that your values are already splitted and written in Sheet2. You didn't reply to my question thought...
@MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst : The `Rows.Count` always give the last row in your sheet, not the samething than the last used row you get with the `End()` function.